# How can I see who notified a user of a Stack Overflow for Teams post?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow-for-teams, notifications

I've asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/c/charcoal/questions/38) today on the Charcoal team. I'm pretty sure I didn't notify the user @Undo, yet he shows up as being notified. Where can I see who did this? The [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/c/charcoal/posts/38/timeline) of the question doesn't show any events.

[image]

Comment: Unless we're a part of the channel we can't see it, so don't feel the need to link to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time, Team subscriptions do not have this capability. There is no way to track this specific activity.